# Кодировка пароля

Tags: кодировка

У меня на сайте стоит кодировка UTF8 и в БД пароли хранятся в данной кодировке, но, когда я ввожу пароль на сайте (при авторизации) он не совпадает с паролем в БД, если же регистрировать нового пользователя с этим же паролем то он совпадает с тем, что и в БД.
Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Попробуйте вывести логин и пароль через echo и сверьте их с данными из БД.

Comment: Для начала, никогда, ни за что, ни при каких обстоятельствах, ни в коем случае **не храните пароли в базе**. Храните хэш с солью.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, ваш вариант подошел)

Comment: @wao138: вот видите, заодно и безопасность кардинально улучшили.

Comment: @VladD Может быть стоит перенести комментарий в ответ? Заодно улучшим статистику подсайта :)

Comment: @tutankhamun: Готово!

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, никогда, ни за что, ни при каких обстоятельствах, ни в коем случае не храните пароли в базе. Храните хэш с солью.

При этом в качестве бонуса будет меньше проблем с кодировкой. И кардинально улучшится безопасность.

Comment: Что-то я не понимаю, как это может решить проблему с разными  кодировками на стороне клиента. Отвлекитесь от пароля, представьте, что вопрос о login-name.

Comment: @avp, вероятно, хэш состоит исключительно из ascii-символов.

Comment: @Qwertiy, очевидно же, что  речь об исходном пароле/логине, т.е. тех байтах от которых считаем хэш (например, md5). У ТС скорее всего получилось только с одной кодировкой. Как только он попробует тем же логином с другой системы (браузер в другой кодировке кириллицы), то все опять не сравниться.

Comment: @avp: Думаю, что проблема была на стороне сервера. Например, база была настроена так, что сохраняла пароли «с потерями».

Comment: Это возможно. Но проблема-то (да хоть с логином) никуда не делась (даже если ТС ее еще не видит (а может ему повезет и он с ней вообще не столкнется?))

Comment: @avp: Я думаю, перенос пароля на сервер организован правильно (этим занимаются фреймворки), а проблема лишь в том, что положенная в базу строка с кириллицей необратимо портится (например, база отконфигурирована так, что не принимает ничего за пределами US-ASCII). По хорошему, надо выяснить истинную причину проблемы. Но раз уж всё равно хранить пароли в базе нельзя, то выяснение причины проблемы можно по идее отложить. (Хотя я бы докопался, будь это моя база.)

Comment: Collation charset у базы и у таблицы в mysql это регулируется, надо установить utf8.